# Can This Classical-Kleene Combination for Intuitionistic Fragment $\{ \neg, \vee, \wedge \}$ Be Extended to Include $\rightarrow$?

Tags: model-theory, intuitionistic-logic, decision-problems

Over a year ago, I worked out a classical-Kleene combination logic that worked to preserve intuitionistic tautologies over the intuitionistic fragment with operators $\{ \neg, \vee, \wedge \}$, which works as follows:

I use $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ to correspond to `false`, `unsure`, and `true`, respectively. Kleene logic has no tautologies, so the move to grant it only intuitionistic tautologies was to do a move I called a "Gilvenko switch" (for the lemma in the theorem that bears his name). Propositional variables receive a unique truth-value column per the normal decision procedure for truth-table semantics for classical logic. When the proposition yields a classical contradiction, $1$ can switch to $0$.

It's a bottom-up procedure, with a structure containing a head Kleene value and a tail truth-table column for each unique atom. I'll give a relevant intuitionistic example below:

Procedure for $\neg \neg (A \vee \neg A)$:

- $\neg \neg ([1,10] \vee \neg [1,10])$, Assignment
- $\neg \neg ([1,10] \vee [1,01])$
- $\neg \neg [1,11]$, preserving that the LEM is not an intuitionistic tautology.
- $\neg \neg [1,1]$, Halving
- $\neg [1,0]$
- $\neg [0,0]$, Switch
- $[2,1]$, maintainting, true to Gilvenko's theorem, that the double-negated LEM is an intuitionistic tautology.

The problem is that this method can't prove $P \rightarrow P$ unless it's interpreted as $\neg (P \wedge \neg P)$. But, that translation allows the DNE -- $(\neg \neg P \rightarrow P)$, translated $\neg (\neg \neg P \wedge \neg P)$.

That's all to be expected, since $\rightarrow$ is independent of the other operators in intuitionistic logic, except $\neg A$ if $\bot$ is also operable, which it is in the above formulation (it's just $[0,0]$).

Most every intuitionistic decision procedure I've found is top-down (propositions-to-atomics), rather than bottom-up (atomics-to-propositions): Beth, Gödel–McKinsey–Tarski translation to S4, lax logic, HA, G4ip. Also, half of them are full-on theorem provers, which are massive overkill for my use case -- building [a (barely started) programming language](https://github.com/hebozhe/lej) with an `unsure` value that adheres to intuitionistic constraints.

**So, is there some means of amending another algorithm that would perform the inverse of the aforementioned "Gilvenko switch", meaning set criteria that would perform an analogous reduction and move $[1,1]$ to $[2,1]$?** Is there any literature on things resembling such a proposal?

The most efficient decision procedure I've found is an $O(n \log{} n)$ [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397508005677). The closest bottom-up approach I've seen is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.13664.pdf).